# alternative for this cursor - sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, cursor

how would I redo this UDF without Cursors to speed up the overall sql?

we have a big and complex sql that gets all a patients active orders,
and for every order (record) the udf is called to get all the AdminTimes for that order, now i cannot eliminate the UDF calling as it does have be called for every order separately 
but at least the generating the AdminTimes within the udf should be sped up as much as possible, currently the server cpu is getting very high and the waiting and locks are accumulating when the user runs this report

the UDF gets all the AdminTimes for a specific RoNo,Split combination from the ReordersAdminTimes table

here is the UDF that uses a cursor to concat into one string all the orders admin times

---

```
    CREATE function dbo.GetAllReorderAdminTimes(
     @FacID nvarchar(6),
     @PatID nvarchar(11),
     @RoNo int,
     @Split int
    ) returns nvarchar(256)
    as
    begin
     declare @times nvarchar(256)
     set @times = ''
     declare @tm nvarchar(50)
     declare @n int
     declare c1 cursor for 
      select coalesce(AdminTimeNo,0),coalesce(AdminTime,'') from ReordersAdminTimes
      where facid = @FacID and RoNo = @RoNo and PatID = @PatID and Split = @Split 
     open c1
     fetch next from c1 into @n,@tm
     while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
      if @n > 1 begin
        set @times = @times + N','
      end
      set @times = @times + @tm
      fetch next from c1 into @n,@tm
     end
     close c1
     deallocate c1
     return @times
    end
```

---

is the above possible to accomplish without the dreaded cursor?

please let me know if any more info is needed...

Thank you
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is totally doable. I have done it in the past a number of times.  Example of one of the UDFs that we used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_Section_GetTimeSlots]
(
    @SectionID INT
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TimeSlots VARCHAR(200)

SELECT @TimeSlots = (COALESCE(@TimeSlots + ', ','') + t.[Name])
FROM 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ts.[Name], ts.[Sequence]
    FROM
        dbo.ScheduledSection ss
        JOIN dbo.TimeSlot ts ON ss.TimeSlotID = ts.TimeSlotID
    WHERE 
        ss.SectionID = @SectionID
    ) AS t
ORDER BY
    t.[Sequence]

RETURN COALESCE(@TimeSlots, '')
END
GO
```

Comment: the new UDF speeded up the sql almost half but was still slow due to the fact that it is still searching thru a very big table (5M Records) but once i utilized your way of getting the results i was able to expand on it to pass a table variable so the result set the udf looks thru is a very small result set vs the full table speeding up the Sql from running 15 minutes to only .03 seconds -- Thanks a mil

Comment: Sweet.  Not a problem.  Glad it was useful.